# django variable in google chart (table) api

Tags: django, google-maps

Iam quite new to Google chart API's and I am trying to integrate it in my currentn django project. Basically, Ive got a django template which looks like the following:

```
<div class="container_24">
<div class="grid_24">
    {% if query %}
        <p>Results</p>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.name }} {{ result.object.salary }} {{ result.object.entry }} {{ result.object.category}}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results found.</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="fclear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything is fine, and I can see my results as expected. Now I insert the google chart API as follows:

```
<div class="container_24">
<div class="grid_24">
{% if query %}
    <p>Results</p>

    {% for result in page.object_list %}
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows(4);
    data.setCell(0, 0, '{{ result.object.name }}');
    data.setCell(0, 1, 10000, '$10,000');
    data.setCell(0, 2, true);
    data.setCell(1, 0, '{{ result.object.name }}');
    data.setCell(1, 1, 8000, '$8,000');
    data.setCell(1, 2, false);
    data.setCell(2, 0, '{{ result.object.name }}');
    data.setCell(2, 1, 12500, '$12,500');
    data.setCell(2, 2, true);
    data.setCell(3, 0, '{{ result.object.name }}');
    data.setCell(3, 1, 7000, '$7,000');
    data.setCell(3, 2, true);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
  }
</script>
..
..
..
```

However, when I do the above, I see the same name for the variable result.object.name. That is, it is not looping through this array. Is there any way to do something like:

```
data.setCell(0:20,0)='{{result.object.name}}'
```

where 0:20 would represent rows of the table/matrix?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand your problem one option would be looping like this:

```
{% for n in result.object.name %}

    data.setCell({{ forloop.counter0 }}, 0, '{{ n }}');

{% endfor %}
```

I'd strongly discourage you from doing this since it's prone to JS injections and you'd have to escape both the Javascript and your template. What i'd suggest is using a Google Chart wrapper: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/

https://github.com/jacobian/django-googlecharts/

http://code.google.com/p/django-graphs/

As far as i remember django-googlecharts works very well and you'll be able to use tags directly into your template.

Comment: Its a shame that a django template tag would be prone to JS type injections. Can you elaborate on this? Is this written/discussed anywhere? Thanks for the other links to chart type tools. I will have a look - Its a pity, the google chart API is actually pretty cool.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't perfectly clear: Django is not the problem. The issue resides in the fact that you can never trust user entered data and shall you want to accept data to be inserted dynamically in charts, that method would be pretty dangerous, unless safely escaped.

Comment: hi Nemo..thanks for this. Cant I use one of the "safe" methods? Something like: {{your.variable|safe}} ? Is this simply not good enough? Many thanks.